# Rails one model two associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User model and a Task model. All users are the same and each user can create a new task and assign that task to another user. In the Task model I have an `assigned_by` column and an `assigned_to` column, so that anyone can create a new task and assign it to anyone else. Later I want to be able for each User to view all tasks assigned to them and all tasks they have assigned to someone else. To do this, I want to setup an association. Is it okay to do something like this?

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'assigned_by'
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'assigned_to'
end
```

Where I have two foreign keys in the same model. Then in the User model I have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Is this the proper way to do something like this?

Comment: Is it ok? No, the second `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'assigned_to'` will overwrite the previous relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you suggested will not work as you can't define 2 methods with the same name (in this case both will be called `user`).

A better way would be calling the relation by what it actually.
For example

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assigned_by, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :assigned_to, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You may also need to add a `foreign_key` option or call the foreign key in the DB `assigned_by_id` and `assigned_to_id`

Also, you will need to change your `User` model as `tasks` method is ambiguous.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks_delegated, foreign_key: 'assigned_by_id', class_name: 'Task'
  has_many :tasks_assigned, foreign_key: 'assigned_to_id', class_name: 'Task'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is to setup three tables:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments, foreign_key: 'assignee_id'
  has_many :assignments_as_assigner, foreign_key: 'assignee_id'
  has_many :tasks, through: :assignments
  has_many :assigned_tasks, through: :assignments_as_assigner
  has_many :created_tasks, class_name: 'Task'
                           foreign_key: 'creator'
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :task
end
```

This creates a one to many association so that a task can be assigned to many users.

Each association in the model has to have a unique name - otherwise you will overwrite the previous association.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this to **prevent overwriting**.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owned_tasks,    class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner,    class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
end
```